# Ajax Calendar showing extra space/bar when clicked on

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio, calendar

I am using AJAXToolKit calendar in visual studio. When I click on the calendar icon, the calendar pops up as it should but a distinct line or strip also pops up which stays after the calendar disappears in image 3. Once both the dates are picked then the additional line disappears. I do not want this line to pop up.  I have been unsuccessful in figuring it out.
Here is what I have done:

```
<td valign="middle" class="inlineChildren textcenter">
<asp:Label id="Show" runat="server" text="Show" />

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShowDays" CssClass="ddlShowDays" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlShowDays_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text=""/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1 day"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7 days"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="14" Text="14 days" Selected="True"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="21" Text="21 days"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="30" Text="30 days"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="60" Text="60 days"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="90" Text="90 days"/>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <span id="pnlDateFrom" runat="server">
    <asp:Label id="lblShowFrom" runat="server" text="from" />

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" Width="6em" MaxLength="10" ToolTip="Example: 1/13/1956" AutoPostBack="true" />
    <ajax:CalendarExtender   PopupPosition= "TopRight" CssClass= "ajax__calendar_container" Animated="false" Enabled="true" EnabledOnClient="true" runat="server" ID="calDateFrom" TargetControlID="txtDateFrom" PopupButtonID="imgCalendarDateFrom"/>

    <asp:ImageMap runat="server" ID="imgmapDateFrom" ImageUrl="~/images/spinner.gif" OnClick="imgmapDateX_Click">
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="0" Bottom="7" Left="0" Right="20" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="up"/>
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="8" Bottom="15" Left="0" Right="20" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="dn"/>
    </asp:ImageMap>

    <asp:Image CssClass="imageLink" ID="imgCalendarDateFrom" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.gif" ToolTip="Choose date from a calendar" />


    </span>
    <span id="panelDateTo" runat="server">
    <asp:Label id="lblShowTo" runat="server" text="to" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTo" runat="server" Width="6em" MaxLength="10" ToolTip="Example: 1/13/1956" AutoPostBack="true" />
    <ajax:CalendarExtender   PopupPosition= "TopLeft" CssClass= "ajax__calendar_container"  Animated="false" Enabled="true" EnabledOnClient="true" runat="server" ID="calDateTo" TargetControlID="txtDateTo" PopupButtonID="imgCalendarDateTo"/>

    <asp:ImageMap runat="server" ID="imgmapDateTo" ImageUrl="~/images/spinner.gif" OnClick="imgmapDateX_Click">
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="0" Bottom="7" Left="0" Right="20" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="up"/>
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="8" Bottom="15" Left="0" Right="20" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="dn"/>
    </asp:ImageMap>

    <asp:Image CssClass="imageLink" ID="imgCalendarDateTo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.gif" ToolTip="Choose date from a calendar" />
    </span>
</td>

<style>
.ajax__calendar_container  
{
  z-index : 1000 ; 
  background-color : Aqua;
 }
.ajax__calendar {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    visibility: visible; display: block;
 }
</style>
```

Here is a link to screenshots of the same.
"https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ldx1aaq29vuxaoy/AAA5VpilqhpruMqgRiEDzIcKa"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. So I thought I will answer my own question.

I was duplicating the ajax_calendar_container in my code as seen using firebug in Firefox. When I removed the cssClass='ajax_calendar_container' from the ajax:CalendarExtender and removed the corresponding code from the style it worked as it should.

```
    <td valign="middle" class="textcenter">
    Show 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShowDays"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlShowDays_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text=""/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1 day"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7 days"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="14" Text="14 days" Selected="True"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="21" Text="21 days"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="30" Text="30 days"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="60" Text="60 days"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="90" Text="90 days"/>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <span id="pnlDateFrom" runat="server">
    <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" text="from"   />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" Width="6em" MaxLength="10" ToolTip="Example: 1/13/1956" AutoPostBack="true" />
    <ajax:CalendarExtender PopupPosition="TopRight" Animated="false" Enabled="true" EnabledOnClient="true" runat="server" ID="calDateFrom" TargetControlID="txtDateFrom" PopupButtonID="imgCalendarDateFrom"  BehaviorID="calendarFrom"  />


    <asp:ImageMap runat="server" ID="imgmapDateFrom" ImageUrl="~/images/spinner.gif" OnClick="imgmapDateX_Click" >
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="0" Bottom="7" Left="0" Right="20" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="up" />
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="8" Bottom="15" Left="0" Right="20" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="dn"/>
    </asp:ImageMap>

    <asp:ImageButton CssClass="imageLink" ID="imgCalendarDateFrom" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.gif" ToolTip="Choose date from a calendar"  />



    &nbsp; 
    </span>
    <span id="pnlDateTo" runat="server">
    <asp:Label id="lblShowTo" runat="server" text="to" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTo" runat="server" Width="6em" MaxLength="10" ToolTip="Example: 1/13/1956" AutoPostBack="true" />
    <ajax:CalendarExtender PopupPosition="TopLeft"  Animated="false" Enabled="true" EnabledOnClient="true" runat="server" ID="calDateTo" TargetControlID="txtDateTo" PopupButtonID="imgCalendarDateTo" BehaviorID="calendarTo"  />

    <asp:ImageMap runat="server" ID="imgmapDateTo" ImageUrl="~/images/spinner.gif" OnClick="imgmapDateX_Click"  >
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="0" Bottom="7" Left="0" Right="20" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="up"/>
    <asp:RectangleHotSpot Top="8" Bottom="15" Left="0" Right="20" HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="dn"/>
    </asp:ImageMap>

    <asp:ImageButton CssClass="imageLink" ID="imgCalendarDateTo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.gif" ToolTip="Choose date from a calendar"  AlternateText="Click to show calendar" />
    &nbsp;
    </span>
</td>
    <style>
     .... removed code
    </style>
```

Here is the link to the screenshots including using firebug to find the change.[Duplicate container found using firebug](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ldx1aaq29vuxaoy/AABJQrE-_eDbU45Pqxv2dbZIa?n=168743011)

Hope this helps someone else facing the same problem!